Call custom .NET within xslt 3.0
I'm new to xslt and I'm trying to use some custom C# code in XSLT3.
While searching I've seen it was done that way in XSLT1 :
<xsl:variable name="CurrentDateTime"
    select="userCSharp:DateCurrentDateTime()" />
 ...
    </xsl:template>
    <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="userCSharp">
    <![CDATA[
        public string DateCurrentDateTime()
        {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string curdate = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string curtime = dt.ToString("T", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string retval = curdate + "T" + curtime;
        return retval;
        }
        ]]>
</msxsl:script>

This is a sample code, mine would be using a custom dll.
but it doesn't seem to work that way in XSLT3 and most topics I found are about using xslt3 within .Net, not the other way around.
https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#extension-functions
https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/extensibility/extension-functions-CS/ext-fns-N.html
But I can't understand how it's supposed to be done.
Would anyone have a simple example?

You might as well just use Razor for this.

Not sure how this is relevant, I have to do it in xslt, can you explain?

This will depend on the XSLT 3 processor and the .NET version you use. So please be specific, are you using SaxonCS and .NET (Core) 6 or later? Do you understand that you will need to write and compile your .NET code separately from the XSLT code, that you can't embed it directly in the XSLT code? An example is online at https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxonmirrorhe/repository/he/revisions/he_mirror_saxon_12_4/entry/src/samples/cs/Examples.cs#L1501.

@MartinHonnen oh sorry, didn't think those info were useful for this, this is a transformation code ran from an Azure standard logic app, not sure which processor is used. The sample  posted in xslt1 is working directly, why do I need to compile the .Net code separatly in xslt3?

that would be for .Net 8

How you can interface with an XSLT processor depends on its implementation; perhaps if Microsoft had made the effort implement XSLT 3 for .NET, like they implemented XSLT 1 for .NET, they would have preserved that feature to embed C# code inline; although they haven't even done that for XSLT 1 and .NET Core. Ask Azure support as to whether and how they support calling .NET code from Azure logic app XSLT 3 code.

I don't know what XSLT 3 processor they use and whether they allow calling .NET code at all; at some time their XSLT 2/3 support was based on Saxon .NET HE 9.8 but that is .NET framework and not .NET 8 anyway.

Just to make it clear that is all very specific on the particular XSLT processor, here is a link to Altova's documentation on calling into .NET: https://www.altova.com/manual/XMLSpy/spyprofessional/fxmisc_net.html. I doubt you find Altova's XSLT processor in Azure apps but the whole question is wrongly framed, there is no general way to call to .NET from any version of XSLT, in the end the mechanisms and interfaces depend on the XSLT processor and the platform.

alright, thank you, I'll look into the doc you provided
